# Motivation for Definition of Derived Category

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra, abelian-categories, derived-functors

On the $n$Lab entry about derived categories, I read the derived category of an abelian category $\mathsf A$ is the localization of $\mathsf{Ch}_\bullet (\mathsf A)$ at the quasi-isomorphisms.

My questions are:

> Why, conceptually, do we want the quasi-isomorphisms to be isomorphisms (apart from their suggestive name)? What purpose would this serve? What exactly happens in derived categories that makes them important?

I know basic algebraic topology and category theory, but no algebraic geometry at all. As preparation I have read sections $5.1-5.3$ of the first volume of the *Handbook of Categorical Algebra* which prove the existence of categories of fractions, describe some specific cases, and show how reflective subcategories are, up to equivalence, categories of fractions. I do not know anything about $\infty$-categories.

Comment: is your question particularly about why localize Ch(A) at the quasi-isomorphisms, or about localizations in general?

Comment: It is particularly about localizing $\mathsf{Ch}_\bullet (\mathsf A)$. I only said what I'd read to alert people answering what I can understand (and what I can't).

Comment: but you also ask what happens in derived categories and what makes them important. Do you mean general derived categories or anything particular to chain complexes?

Comment: Oh, I did not know about "general derived categories"! I would certainly appreciate information about them aswell!

Comment: The basic motivation is that we want to identify objects with their resolutions, since to compute derived functors we end up replacing objects with resolutions anyway. To learn more you should probably read a textbook on homological algebra.

Comment: Where would you recommend I start?

Comment: That depends on where you want to go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quasi-isomorphisms in the category of chain complexes are related to homotopy theory, and in a sense localizing at the quasi-isomorphisms is like localizing topological spaces at the homotopy equivalences. It is primarily a computational tool for chain complexes and resolutions of various objects.

The purpose achieved by localizing, in general, is that you obtain a new category in which what was previously only weak equivalences (or quasi-isomorphisms or whatever you want to call them) are now actual isomorphisms. The story is as follows.

In a category you always have a notion of isomorphisms. Quite often though you have a category but you also have a notion of equivalency which is weaker than that described by isomorphisms. In other words, you have a bunch of morphisms which included the isomorphisms, and you think of objects for which such an arrow exists between them as essentially the same. For instance, in $Top$ isomorphism corresponds to homeomorphism, but being homotopy equivalent is strictly weaker. For a topologist, working in $Top$ is quite fine. For a homotopy theorist, working in $Top$ is not so fine, since it isn't really the right category for the homotopy theorist to work in - its notion of isomorphic objects is too strict. So, the homotopy theorist really wants a category of topological spaces where homotopy equivalences are actually the isomorphisms in the category. In other categories similar situations arise.

The most obvious way to turn all the weak equivalences into actual isomorphisms is to turn them into isomorphisms, by brute force. This is technically difficult though and results in poorly manageable categories. There are various techniques for localizing a category that can assist in producing something more manageable.

Comment: Itay, you said localizing at quasi-isomorphisms makes computations with chain complexes easier but then that localization generally yields poorly manageable categories. I'm confused.

Comment: I also said there are various ways to obtaining more manageable derived categories.

Comment: @Exterior: do you know about the classical derived functors? I think in order to really appreciate $\mathscr{D}(A)$ you should learn about these first

Comment: I think localizing at the quasi-isomorphisms is much more like localizing at the weak equivalences, not the homotopy equivalences. If you want to invert homotopy equivalences you can just pass to the homotopy category. Passing to the derived category is different and harder.

Comment: Indeed @QiaochuYuan I was attempting to frame things in something more immediate to grasp as it seems OP was lacking that understanding. My very weak statements made in the first paragraph meant to reflect that. Anyways, thanks for the comment that clarifies this.